# How to secure Amazon EC2 with Tomcat7 and mySQL

Tags: security, amazon-ec2

I'm very new with EC2. I have Tomcat 7 and MySQL installed. The security group I have setup is

Custom TCP Rule
TCP
8080

SSH
TCP
22

MYSQL
TCP
3306

For Outbound
It is for all Traffic.

*I got a report from Amazon said as below*

*Instance ID: i-1e42db06*
 *AWS ID: 772517067349*
 *Reported Activity: DoS*

What should I do to stop it?

And I also got a bill as below
*$0.090 per GB - first 10 TB / month data transfer out beyond the global free tier 637.521 GB*

Please advice me steps to protect my instance in EC2

**Updated: with email from Amazon**
We've received a report(s) that your EC2 instance(s)

AWS ID: 772517067349

Instance Id: i-1e42db06
 IP Address: 172.31.25.202

has been implicated in activity that resembles a Denial of Service attack against remote hosts; please review the information provided below about the activity.

Please take action to stop the reported activity and reply directly to this email with details of the corrective actions you have taken. If you do not consider the activity described in these reports to be abusive, please reply to this email with details of your use case.

If you're unaware of this activity, it's possible that your environment has been compromised by an external attacker, or a vulnerability is allowing your machine to be used in a way that it was not intended

Answer (score 0):

Check the instance monitoring panel in EC2 to see your traffic and check the logs in your server to see what kind of traffic is is.

Mysql has just had a zero day exploit that you could be vulnerable to, and SSH has had quite a few critical bugs lately, so it's not only your firewall settings that you need to take into account here, but you need to secure the services behind those ports too.

Besides this, if your web application deployed in tomcat contains a vulnerability, you are open to all sort of attacks, many of which will be reflected in an increase of traffic. Tomcat itself, of course, must also be up to date and properly secured.

There's just too many things that could be happening to enumerate, but if the "transfer out" as it's worded in your question refers to outbound traffic, you could have been compromised and have the server be part of a botnet. It's not clear above if they are reporting to you that you are suffering a DoS or you are trying a DoS.

Comment: I have faced the same problem...apparently AWS automatically created a new instance and deployed my application .....but this incident repeated many times.....I am also new to AWS. Please help.